# Accessing array with string key

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, append, appendchild

I'm generating html elements from a JSON object `tableobj` and assign them to an array `elementArray` through the `generate()` function, this works great, but the problem is when I pass `elementArray` to the `assemble()` function I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

What I'm looking for is to have the output from `assemble()` structure the table, which is based of the `binding` property.

For example: appending `<thead>` to `<table>` therefore `<thead>`'s binding would be 0 since its parent element is `elementArray[0]` which would be the `<table>`. This same pattern for `<tr>` would be 00 since it would be `<table>` child element `0` which would be `<thead>`, etc...

//CODE

```
<script>
var tableobj = [
        {table:{binding:""}},
        {thead:{binding:"0"}},
        {tbody:{binding:"0"}},
        {tr:{binding:"00"}},
        {th:{binding:"000"}},
        {th:{binding:"000"}},
        {th:{binding:"000"}}
];

function init(){
    //GENERATE HTML & BIND PROPERTIES
    var elementArray = generate(tableobj);
    console.log(elementArray);

    //ASSEMBLE THE TABLE --- example: elementArray[0].appendChild(thead) 
    var elementAssembly = assemble(elementArray);

    console.log(elementAssembly);
    console.log(elementAssembly[0]);
    //OUTPUT
    //TABlE->THEAD
    //TABlE->THEAD
    //TABlE->THEAD->TR
    //TABlE->THEAD->TR->TH
    //TABlE->THEAD->TR->TH
    //TABlE->THEAD->TR->TH
}
function assemble(o){   
    o.forEach(function(ele){
        var position = ele.position.replace(/0/g,"[0]");
        var position = ele.position.split('');
        if(ele.position.length > 0){
            //WHERE MY QUESTION LIES....
            var parent = o[position];
            parent.appendChild(ele);
        }
    });
    return o;
};
function generate(o){
    var struct = o.map(function(ele,i){
        var element = document.createElement(Object.keys(ele));
        for(prop in ele){
            var key = Object.keys(ele[prop]);
            key.forEach(function(attr){
                switch(attr){
                    case "binding":
                        Object.defineProperty(element,'position',{
                            value: ele[prop][attr]
                        });
                        break;          
                }
            });         
        }
        return element;
    })
    return struct;
}

//ONLOAD TRIGGER INIT
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, what is your question? Can you give some sample output? I have no clue what you want... You can append something to an array using [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: why `appendChind` ? are you working with DOM elements ? If so, show some fragment from the DOM tree with those elements

Comment: my output would be the element being appended to the correct node within the array.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the `myArray` is an array of HTML elements already created, I'm now trying to loop through and append them to the correct locations.

Comment: What is `myArray`, what is `myelement`, what are you trying to accomplish? You explanation makes no sense to me. `000` is not a length.

Comment: @JordanDavis, an array of HTML elements or HTMLCollection?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest array of HTML elements sorry should of stated that.

Comment: @usandfriends what are you even talking about `000` is not a length... think of a form which would contain (table, thead, tbody, tr, th, etc..) I am trying to bind them dynamically based of a json property, aka the "string". for instance `<thead>` gets bound to `<table>` therefore its position property would be `[0]` because table would be the parent.... `myarray[0].appendChild(`thead`);`

Comment: Add code showing your expected output. Despite your comments this question still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's obvious from the code what he's trying to do: he has a string containing the subscripts, which may be an arbitrary depth in the nested arrays.

Comment: @JordanDavis Okay, so edit your question and fix all vague points.

Comment: @usandfriends doing so right now give me one sec.

Comment: posted the full code with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the characters in the binding, getting the child element for each to drill down into the DOM. When you get to the end, append the new element as a child.

```
function assemble(o){   
    o.forEach(function(ele){
        var position = ele.position;
        if (position.length == 0) { 
            return;
        }
        var cur = o[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < position.length; i++) {
            cur = cur.children[position[i]];
        }
        cur.appendChild(ele);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still didn't work... I posted my full source above.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the code you posted. This answer was for your original question, where `mystring` contains a sequence of numeric array indexes like `"[0][1][23]"`.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that creates a string like `[0][1][23]`. The `forEach` statement operates on an array, not a string.

Comment: yea I tried a different format but here I'll edit it out.... `console.log(position)` after the `.replace()`

Comment: Ahh, I see it in `ele.position.replace(/0/g`.

Comment: But then you do `position = ele.position.split('')`, which converts `position` into an array. You can't do `o[position]` when `position` is an array.

Comment: Yea like I said I was trying different formats out but I've tried both ways.

Comment: You understand what I'm trying to do though... append `thead`,`tbody` to `table` then `tr` to `thead` then `th` to `tr`.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't understand why you're using a string like `000` to indicate where each element gets appended. Why not just a number like `3` to mean it's 3 levels down?

Comment: Nice! well I was thinking of accessing the parent like an array... for example,  `formArray[0]` would be table `formArray[0][0]` would be thead `formArray[0][1]` would be tbody. How would you declare with just 3?

Comment: So would the binding contain something like `"01"` for that? What if you need to access an index higher than 9? You need to put delimiters into the string.

Comment: yea exactly `tbody` would be `"01"` I hope nothing is that nested but yea the goal is to have it dynamic so yea it would 9 integers for the property.

Comment: I guess then it would be `cur.children[position[i]]` instead of `cur.firstChild`.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much for you time/help! much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand what you are trying to accomplish:

Take the following string and array

```
var str = "[0][0]";
var arr = [["a"], ["b"]];

eval("arr" + str);
=> "a"
```

Here you have bracketed into the array based on your dynamic string.

The code equivalent of this eval would be:

```
arr[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this. It uses the given path as index for the array `code`.

```js
var path = '[0][0][0]',
    code = [];

function setValue(array, path, value) {
    var pathA = path.match(/\d+/g),
        index = pathA.pop(); //  save last index for access
    pathA.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!(a in r)) {
            r[a] = [];
        }
        return r[a];
    }, array)[index] = value;
}

function getValue(array, path) {
    return path.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r[a];
    }, array);
}

setValue(code, path, 42);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(code, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(getValue(code, path));
```